# AttributeError : Module object has not attribute 'download'

Tags: python, download, nltk, attributeerror

I am getting this `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newyear1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 31, in <module>
    from nltk import compat
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/compat.py", line 65, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/Users/JK/Documents/csv.py", line 2, in <module>
    """
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'download'
```

I am assuming this error is because the `csv.py` file is somehow still somewhere in the cache? The new file name is `newyear1.py`. But I do not understand this error, especially that if I try to update `nltk`, it tells me that it is up to date.

Comment: `import nltk; nltk.download('popular')`

Comment: The message is about error in " import csv File "/Users/JK/Documents/csv.py" , which is an older file that I am not working out of. the NLTK downloader is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It was rather another newbie moment. The file I was working with was formatted wrong. I solved the issue by creating a new file into a new directory.

Comment: Use `pip` or `conda` and virtual environments to prevent this from happening: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ . And make sure you have no files or modules names that clashes with the library (i.e. NLTK) or native python builtins https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html